# Runtime Error or Generating Error | WebUI generate a image showing many fragements

Tags: python, macos, stable-diffusion, webui

Environment

- Mac OS Ventura 13.2.1
- Intel Core I9 8 core
- AMD Radeon Pro 5500m 4GB
- 16GB Memory

I want to just show demo with using WebUI. So I need to just WebUI working.

```
COMMANDLINE_ARGS="--skip-torch-cuda-test --upcast-sampling --no-half-vae --use-cpu interrogate --precision full --no-half --opt-split-attention-v1"
```

I'm using arguments above. And It seems like working well at moment, but the result is very bad.
The example here.

[error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imi09.jpg)

When I removed the argument, "--opt-split-attention-v1", another error was made.

> RuntimeError: MPS backend out of memory (MPS allocated: 5.05 GB, other allocations: 2.24 GB, max allowed: 6.77 GB). Tried to allocate 1024.00 MB on private pool. Use PYTORCH_MPS_HIGH_WATERMARK_RATIO=0.0 to disable upper limit for memory allocations (may cause system failure).

I guess that the graphic card memory is too lower to run WebUI by my mac.
But using DiffusionBee, I can make new image by same mechanism.

[working well in DiffusionBee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRtSd.jpg)

Why I can't make image by WebUI? What is difference between WebUI and DiffussionBee?

Comment: Ok, I found the answer. I just add argument `--use-cpu all` with `--no-half`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. I just add argument `--use-cpu all` with `--no-half`.
And I remove argument `--opt-split-attention-v1`.
It takes longer time to generate new image, but WebUI is working.